# How to test a class with bound properties

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, dependency-properties

I am trying to write a unit test for the code below, specifically to test the Calculate method of the ModelUnderTest class. Despite a few attempts and Goolgling I am stumped.

The crux of the issue is that the model makes use of a property that is bound to a property of another class (that property is also bound in my actual code - not shown here). The property is read-only in both classes, so I can't just set it.

I'd like to mock (or stub) the IService class, but I am beginning to wonder if that is possible in this case.

Here is the code:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Testing
{
    public interface IService
    {
        int Option { get; }
    }

    public class ConcreteService : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ActiveOptionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ActiveOption", typeof(int), typeof(ConcreteService), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public int ActiveOption { get { return (int) GetValue(ActiveOptionProperty); } }
    }

    public class ModelUnderTest : DependencyObject
    {
        private readonly IService _service;

        public ModelUnderTest(IService service)
        {
            _service = service;
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(this,
                                         CurrentOptionProperty,
                                         new Binding
                                         {
                                             Source = _service,
                                             Path = new PropertyPath(ConcreteService.ActiveOptionProperty)
                                         });

        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentOptionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Option", typeof(IService), typeof(ModelUnderTest), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public int Option
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(CurrentOptionProperty); }
        }

        public int Calculate()
        {
            return Option + 7;
        }

    }
```

If I have a test like so:

```
[TestClass]
public class ModelUnderTestTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Calculate_Test()
    {
        var service = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IService>();
        var target = new ModelUnderTest(service);

        // Do something to make target's Option value be '3'
        target.Calculate().Should().Be(10);
    }
}
```

What can I do to make this test pass?

Comment: you can have a different configuration for your IOC container for the unit tests.

Comment: The fundamental problem here is that you have a tight coupling between  `ConcreteService` and `ModelUnderTest`. Breaking that tight coupling is your first step.